# Does maintaining a lower indoor temperature cost the same heating energy as maintaining a higher indoor temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

When heating in a house is on in winter, does maintaining a higher house temperature cost the same amount of energy as maintaining a lower house temperature?

I often heard that it will not save heating utility (gas or electricity) if adjust a house's thermo controller to a lower temperature, as far as maintaining the temperature (after reaching to the temperature) is concerned.

Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is typically "no, they are not the same" (see linked duplicate).  This is not something you should expect from a well-designed heating system.

Comment: How shall I save energy used by a heating system?

Comment: Lowering the target temperature is an easy way to do it (as mentioned in that other answer).  There are also plenty of ways to make your house more thermally efficient.  It could be a more efficient heating system, better thermal insulation in your house, etc.  It's a really broad topic.  There are entire engineering associations dedicated to looking at heating and how it relates to efficiency and comfort.